# Id POST as hidden field but null in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("QuoteUpdate", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.DropDownList("network", Model.availableNetworks);
@Html.DropDownList("grade", Model.grades);
@Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Product.id);

<button type="submit">Get Quote</button>
}
```

And a controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult QuoteUpdate(int? id, string network, string grade )
    {
    }
```

The `id` property is always null after form is submitted.  I have checked source and the hidden field has the correct value in the rendered HTML.

I cannot figure out why this parameter is always null.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're accessing a nested property on your model, the generated HTML is probably something like this:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="Product_id" name="Product.id" />
```

When your form gets posted to the controller action, there's not a parameter that matches up with `Product.Id`.

You could work around this by changing the generated name of the `input` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810100/asp-net-mvc-4-override-emitted-html-name-and-id) for more about how to do that):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Product.id, new { Name = "id" });
```

Which will generate:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="Product_id" name="id" />
```

Then things should model bind correctly.